# Getting Response timeout exceptions while using BleDriver.NET for BLED112 device

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to communicate with BLED112 device using the C# driver interface :
https://github.com/ahouben/BleDriver.NET

While debugging i can confirm that I am able to successfuly establish connection with BLE device.

But when i call the method `ble_cmd_system_get_info` , i am getting 
*Response timeout* message.

Following is the line where I am facing issues :

```
 if (!m_waitHandleResponse.WaitOne(5000))
 {
    throw new BgApiException("Response timeout");
 }
```

I tried to increase the timeout duration, but it didn't helped.

I am using Windows 7 environment.